# How to launch kate from cscope?

Tags: kate

I tried setting `EDITOR` to `kate` and starting `cscope`. Unfortunately, whevenever cscope launches kate:

```
kate +LINE FILE.c
```

the editor ignores the +*line* flag treating it as just another (non-existant) file instead of opening the *file.c* on the requested line...

I can't believe, the editor can be quite so stupid -- there must be a trick to make it work properly. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user14164's answer above for the pointer. Looking through cscope's own man-page, I found a way to teach it, how to invoke editors, which -- like kate -- don't recognize the +*LINE* notation. By launching cscope this way:

```
env CSCOPE_LINEFLAG=-l%s CSCOPE_EDITOR=kate cscope
```

Then, by replacing `kate` with a wrapper, that launches real `kate` in the background (with kate's chatty stderr redirected to `/dev/null`)

```
#!/bin/sh
exec kate "$@" 2> /dev/null &
```

I get the gvim-like functionality (where cscope remains available while the launched editor is running) without gvim's multitude of windows.

Answer (score 1):

According to 'kate --help', to open a file and jump to a certain line, you have to use the '-l' argument, instead of '+':

```
kate -l LINE FILE.c
```

Works for me (command line, not cscope).